# Other answers on how to empty trash via command line are not working

Tags: command-line, vnc, gnome-classic, delete, trash

Where else can I find files that are showing up in my trash can?

Ubuntu 12.04, Headless, VNC, Gnome-fallback.

I have a stubborn trash can that I suspect is from deleting files from command that belonged to me, but was deleted as root. I think the deleted files were from another drive, but I'm not sure. I delete stuff as root all the time and it doesn't show up in my trash, but something is different with this scenario.

The common answer is:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

But this command does not work. My user and the root user do not have any files or folders in the `.local/share/Trash` folder, yet my user trash can has big files that I cannot find on the system to delete.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I remembered that the deleted folders were on a NAS, a Drobo5N to be exact.  They are somehow showing up in my desktop trash can now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they show up in the Trash section they must be somewhere, I suggest you to run:

```
$ sudo find / -iname "*name_of_one_of_those_big_files*"
```

And wait to see if it shows anything.

Comment: Thank you so much. They were under /media/drobo/.Trash-1000/  Deleting these files freed up about 40 GB.

Comment: I tried to increment your response as the correct answer, but I don't have enough points to do so yet.

Comment: @DonSchaefer as the original poster of the question, you can accept an answer by clicking on the grey tick icon next to it.